# Как редактировать inline кнопки, когда они списком?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Тг бот на aiogram хочу чтоб был лист inline кнопок, и при нажатии на которых у них в названии появлялась "галочка". Но не могу понять как в callback передать название кнопки, или ее айди, чтоб отредактировать именно нужную кнопку. Подскажите как это сделать с моей реализацией кода. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
dp.callback_query(lambda cb: cb.data == "press_button")(self.press_button)

    async def press_button(self, cb_query:CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    print(f"CONSOLE LOG{cb_query}")
    await cb_query.message.edit_text(
        text=f"EDITED",
        reply_markup=Keyboards.SURVEY_UPDATE,
    )
SURVEY_UPDATE = Keyboard.create_inline(
    [
        {"text": "Full name", "callback_data": "press_button"},
        {"text": "Number", "callback_data": "press_button"},
    ]
)
```